# celery result_backend with postgresql - null for some fields in the task table

Tags: celery

I am using Celery for a POC. My objective is to create a workflow across a distributed system.

For the purpose of a POC I have created a couple of docker containers each with a worker started with the queue option. I initiated a chain from yet another container. The chain executes successfully across the containers. Now I decided to enable the `result_backend` to store the results of each task getting executed.

I set the `result_backend` to `postgresql` with the schema option. After executing the chain now, I do see the tables created in postgres. However the `task_meta` table has some columns as null (e.g. the worker, queue.) Where as the `task_id` and status are correctly populated.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that there were no workers to receive the task, and it still got the default values?

Comment: Actually both the tasks in the chain got executed - with result of one passed to the other. I was unable to check what are the values for the args in the DB it being a bytea type.

Answer (score 7):

I know it has been a long time since you asked the question but I hope it will help others.

By default, Celery does not write all task result attributes to the backend.
Your have to configure it by setting `result_extended` to `True` as stated here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-extended

So if you configure your app from python you will have to do something like:

```
import celery

app = Celery(
    broker=broker_url,
    backend=postgresq_url,
)

app.conf.update(result_extended=True)
```